# How to change the editor default color to some other color in grapesjs in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grapesjs

[image]

How to change this default color into some other color in grapesjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it using the CSS, using red as an example:

```
.gjs-one-bg { background-color: 'red' }
```

There is a lot of other classes you can alter as well, use Chrome dev tools to inspect them. Make sure to add `!important` if the styles don't apply.